# What value to use to find complex impedance of a motor?

Tags: power-supply, motor, impedance, efficiency

Output of motor is 3000 W with efficiency of 0.8, so The input power is 3750 W. when I want to find the complex impedance of the motor **Z = X + jY** i get fail answer when I use P = 3750 W to calculate the answer. 
The equation I use is Zm = E^2 / Sm, where S = P-jQ. Q=2250 VAR and E=230V.

I get the right answer with 3000 W though, but still need some explanation. Anyone?
thnx

Comment: You wrote "efficiency=0.8" Did you mean "the power factor is 0.8" ? Only power factor has a connection to complex impedance. Efficiency means something else, it tells how much of the total used energy is transformed usefully to other form and how much is dissipated.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments suggest, you are confusing power factor (pf) with efficiency.

$$pf = \frac {P} {S}$$

\$S = \frac {P} {pf} = \frac {3000 W} {0.8} = 3750V\cdot A\$

\$S = P + jQ_L = \sqrt {P^2 + Q_L^2}= \sqrt {(3000W)^2 + (2250 VAR)^2} = 3750V\cdot A\$

Efficiency can also be added, but you'd have to be given current.